# Is $\mathbb{Z}^*_{15} = \{1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 11, 13, 14\}.$ $\mathbb{Z}^*_{15}$ isomorphic to this subgroup of $S_8?$

Tags: abstract-algebra

NOTES:

(1) $\sigma_{2,2}$ is the set of permutations in $S_4$ with two two-cycles

(2) $\mathbb{Z}^*_{15} = \{1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 11, 13, 14\}.$

$\mathbb{Z}^*_{15}$ has two elements of order 3 and 4 elements of order 4.

By Cayley's Theorem, $\mathbb{Z}^*_{15}$ is isomorphic to some subgroup of $S_8.$

Since $$H = \sigma_{2,2} \cup \{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 & 3 & 2 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 4 & 3 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 & 4 & 2 \end{pmatrix}\},$$ is a subgroup of $S_8,$ with 3 elements of order 2 and 4 elements of order 4, **is $H$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^*_{15}?$**

If not, how do you find out which subgroup of $S_8$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^*_{15}?$

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}^*_{15}$ is isomorphic to $Z_2 \times Z_4$ there is no element of order $3$ in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things wrong with your suggested $H$:

- The group $S_4$ has no subgroup of order eight containing four elements of order four.
- All the subgroups of $S_4$ with eight elements are isomorphic to the dihedral group $D_4$ of symmetries of a square. Each and every one of them has two elements of order four, five elements of order two, and the identity.
- Anyway, your $H$ is not a subgroup.
- Also, $\Bbb{Z}_{15}^*$ is abelian, but the dihedral group is not, so they cannot be isomorphic.

---

To get a subgroup of $S_8$ isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_{15}$ use the Cayley action. Label the elements of $S_8$ as $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_8\}$ in some order (different orders give rise to conjugate subgroups of $S_8$), and map the element $x\in\Bbb{Z}_{15}$ to the permutation $f(x)\in S_8$ determined by $f(x)(i)=j$, where $x x_i=x_j$, $i=1,2,\ldots,8$. For example, if we list the elements in the order $x_1=1$, $x_2=2$, $x_3=4$, $x_4=7$, $x_5=8$, $x_6=11$, $x_7=13$,$x_8=14$, then 
$$f(2)=(1235)(4876)$$
because multiplication by two permutes $1\mapsto 2\mapsto 4\mapsto8\mapsto 1$, and $7\mapsto14\mapsto13\mapsto11\mapsto7$. That is, two disjoint 4-cycles
$(x_1x_2x_3x_5)(x_4x_8x_7x_6)$. Pick the subscripts from this to get $f(2)\in S_8$.

One of the subgroups you are looking for is the image of $f$.